# Can't connect 3.5 inch HDD with external USB 2.0 to SATA enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, 16.10, usb-drive

So I got a cheap external HDD enclosure keep my 2 TB Seagate desktop HDD in. When I connect it to my PC the drive spins up but it's not being detected. `lsblk` does not even show the device.

This is the enclosure: http://picclick.ca/35-inch-Silver-USB-20-SATA-External-HDD-272225265854.html (I got it from a dutch store, but it's the same product)

When I leave it connected for a while it spins down and then immediately spins up again, and it keeps going like that.

I've tried multiple USB ports: front, back, 2.0, 3.0 and even those red ones, but all give the same result. I've also tried multiple USB cables, multiple enclosures (I ordered 2 of them) and multiple drives.

`dmesg` shows this when I connect it:

```
[30190.011368] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=6116
[30190.011369] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[30190.011370] usb 3-7: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[30190.011371] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Generic     
[30190.011371] usb 3-7: SerialNumber: 116AC2101219
[30190.011829] usb-storage 3-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[30190.012203] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-7:1.0
[30190.198847] usb 3-7: USB disconnect, device number 41
[30190.498697] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[30196.259064] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[30201.655373] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
[30207.027682] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[30212.844062] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
[30218.292382] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
[30223.668670] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 50 using xhci_hcd
[30229.044986] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 51 using xhci_hcd
[30234.421307] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 52 using xhci_hcd
[30239.801664] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 53 using xhci_hcd
[30245.169963] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 54 using xhci_hcd
[30250.550293] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 55 using xhci_hcd
[30255.930596] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
[30261.298904] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[30266.711247] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[30272.059572] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
[30277.427898] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
[30282.844207] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
[30288.180528] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
[30293.560835] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[30298.937162] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[30304.313481] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[30309.689807] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 66 using xhci_hcd
[30315.066128] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 67 using xhci_hcd
[30326.618790] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
[30331.959152] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
[30337.343444] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
[30342.719754] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 71 using xhci_hcd
[30348.092089] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 72 using xhci_hcd
[30353.468427] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 73 using xhci_hcd
[30358.848717] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 74 using xhci_hcd
[30364.225059] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 75 using xhci_hcd
[30369.597368] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 76 using xhci_hcd
[30374.977686] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
[30380.346017] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
[31263.434593] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 87 using xhci_hcd
[31268.974897] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 88 using xhci_hcd
[31274.359240] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 89 using xhci_hcd
[31279.731545] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 90 using xhci_hcd
[31285.107878] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 91 using xhci_hcd
[31291.248214] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 95 using xhci_hcd
[31296.912536] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[31303.608959] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 103 using xhci_hcd
[31309.169300] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 104 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Have you tried it in another computer? Also check the power supply.

Comment: Most but not all USB external boxes work with Ubuntu. It is usually possible to boot from them. But I don't know this brand name. Have you tried in another computer? Do you know if the HDD itself is working?

Comment: The disk itself works fine, when I put it in the harddrive tray of my PC I can use it normally. I've also tried connecting it to my Pine64 (running ubuntu server edition 16.04.1), which produces the same results. Though I have managed to mount it once, but it errored after a while and the drive letter kept changing (sda, sdb, sdc, sdd).

It looks like the enclosure itself is not branded, I can't find any brand name on the outside nor the inside. I guess that's what I get for choosing the cheapest product I can find..

Comment: Check if manufacturer recommends using a powered hub.